# Select-Object of multiple properties

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find an elegant way to put the metadata of a table of type System.Data.DataTable into a multi-dimensional array for easy reference in my program. My approach to the issue so far seems tedious.

Assuming `$DataTable` being the `DataTable` in question

What I tried to do so far was:

```
$Types = $DataTable.Columns | Select-Object -Property DataType
$Columns= $DataTable.Columns | Select-Object -Property ColumnName
$Index = $DataTable.Columns | Select-Object -Property ordinal
$AllowNull  = $DataTable.Columns | Select-Object -Property AllowDbNull
```

Then painfully going through each array, pick up individual items and put them in my multi-dimensional array `$TableMetaData`.

I read in the documentation of `Select-Object` and it seems to me that only 1 property can be selected at 1 time? I think I should be able to do all the above more elegantly and store the information in `$TableMetaData`.

Is there a way to easily pick up multiple properties and put them in a multi-dimensional array in 1 swoop?

Comment: What do you mean by multi-dimensional array? A jagged array, or an actual multi-dimensional array? Please show your code for creating `$TableMetaData`

Comment: @mathia: like $TableMetaData[,,,] or something like $TableMetaData[][][] Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I read the documentation of Select-Object and it seems to me that only 1 property can be selected at 1 time?

This is not true, `Select-Object` can take any number of arguments to the `-Property` parameter

```
$ColumnInfo = $DataTable.Columns | Select-Object -Property DataType,ColumnName,ordinal,AllowDbNull
```

Now `$ColumnInfo` will contain one object for each column, having all 4 properties.

Rather than using a multi-dimensional array, you should consider using a hashtable (`@{}`, an unordered dictionary):

```
$ColumnInfo = $DataTable.Columns | ForEach-Object -Begin { $ht = @{} } -Process {
    $ht[$_.ColumnName] = $_
} -End { return $ht }
```

Here, we create an empty hashtable `$ht` (the `-Begin` block runs just once), then store each column object in `$ht` using the `ColumnName` as the key, and finally return `$ht`, storing it in `$ColumnInfo`.

Now you can reference metadata about each column by Name:

```
$ColumnInfo.Column2
# or 
$ColumnInfo["Column2"]
```

Comment: hmm.. I thought I did the same thing and got an error.. I must have used -expandproperty then.

Comment: @user1205746 `-ExpandProperty` takes only one string as it's argument, so that makes sense

Comment: Is it possible to convert that multi-dimensional array to something dictionary like? For example: Currently, if I would like to access columnName2 I have to get $ColumnInfo[1]. Is there a way to frame the output so that if I want to access the column, I only need to issue $ColumnInfo.ColumnName2?

Comment: That's awesome! This is exactly what I wanted! I have hard time trying to access the multi-dimension array. It does not work like C where I can use $TableInfo[0,1] to get item in row 1 column 2.

Comment: One more question: I saw in the -process you have included everything by using $ht[$_.ColumnName]= $_. If I only want to include only $_.ordinal, $_.DataType and $_.AllowDbNull, how should I do that?

Comment: See the first example again, `$ht[$_.ColumnName]= $_ |Select-Object DataType,ColumnName,Ordinal,AllowDbNull` :-)

Comment: Ah! My apologies... I am new to all this and I am not that smart yet to use these goodies to my advantage... appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do this is to create an "empty" variable with Select-Object. Here is a sample command:

```
$DataTableReport = "" | Select-Object -Property DataType, ColumnName, ordinal,  AllowDbNull
```

Then, link the $DataTableReport to the $Types, $Columns, $Index, and the $AllowNull properties as shown below:

```
$DataTableReport.Types = $DataTable.DataType
$DataTableReport.Columns = $DataTable.ColumnName 
$DataTableReport.Index = $DataTable.ordinal 
$DataTableReport.AllowNull  = $DataTable.AllowDbNull
```

Finally, call the DataTableReport variable.

`$DataTableReport` # will display all the results in a tabular form.